# Website Structure is different on mobile than on PC browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typo3

I have an issue where, when viewing my page on a smartphone/tablet, the sections are positioned wrongly. It is a typo3 project, and it's about applying filters to a search page.

The issue occurs when you press on "extended search". A new section appears under the "extended search" button, where you can choose different filters, however on the smartphone/tablet viewport the section appears on top of the section which includes the "extended search button".

Could anybody help me? I can ofcourse provide more information or code snippets if necessary!

Thanks in advance,
Malik

ps: I listed all programming languages that are used in the project, as I dont know which one is causing the issue.

/e:

the section which appears when the button is clicked:

```
<section ng-if="options.hideFilterForm == true">
```

the section with the button is something like this:

```
<f:layout name="Search" >
<f:section name="main">
```

Comment: You can use `@media` queries to make your website work on mobile better. DId you try it?

Comment: Please make a fiddle or code snippets example of your problem.

Comment: I dont think Im allowed to post the code because of work reasons.. But I uploaded a reproduction of the code.

Comment: are media queries been used?

Comment: yes, media queries are already used in the project!